# How I can get attribute from request Jmeter

Tags: java, spring-security, jmeter

I need to get a csrfToken from the session that is in the request attributes, and put in POST request, how I can do it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-form) you will find the token in the response in form of [HTML hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) looking like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${A}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

so you will be able to use [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) to get the token value and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you will be able to re-use it later on where required.

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)